# Firefox generating error?

Tags: firefox, javascript, firebug

I run Firebug on my computer since I develop websites. And I have been noticing this error consistently with every page I go to and I am lost as to what it is and believe it might be Firefox causing this error. Has anyone seen it before? Here is the error:

```
An exception occurred. Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "resource://jid1-g0j5yenav9jwla-at-jetpack-api-utils-lib/tabs/tab.js",
line 254, in null .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation) 
Error: Permission denied for <http://superuser.com> to create wrapper for 
object of class UnnamedClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must of been a bug in Firefox or even Firebug. I updated both in the past few days and th errors have gone away.